# Prime labelling of graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, prime-numbers, graph-colorings, applications

A  prime labeling of a graph is an injective function $f: V(G) \to \{1, 2, ..., |V(G)|\}$
such that for every pair of adjacent vertices $u$ and $v$, $\text{gcd}(f(u), f(v)) = 1$ (labels of any two adjacent vertices are relatively prime).

What can *prime labeling* be useful for? I was thinking of any applications like scheduling etc. but I'm not sure.

Comment: Entertaining mathematicians... Cubic lattices were considered in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/162173

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A somewhat fanciful "application."

Suppose nodes represent museum guard stations, and arcs represent lines
of sight between stations.
The labels represent shift hours: hours at one station before a
guard is replaced by a fresh guard.

Then a prime labeling ensures that when there is a change of guard at one
station, there is not simultaneously a change of guard at all the adjacent
stations, until the lcm of the labels in the neighborhood
is reached.
So those guard(s) can monitor the change and ensure coverage.

---

[image: PrimeGraph]

[image]

---

This schedule fails at $t=2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 30$, when
no guard covers $B$.

Alternatively, the nodes can represent employees and the arcs
employees with similar skills, so again when a shift change occurs,
the skill set is covered during the switch.

Comment: (Thanks to @Waldemar for an earlier correction.)

Comment: This is quite fanciful--it seems the museum would be better served if all shifts had the same lengths and staggered start times.  Then at most one post would be empty at any time.

Comment: @DanielLitt: Ha! Point taken. But in this museum, all galleries open simultaneously at 9:00AM. :-)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke thanks a lot! but I don't get why *"This schedule fails at t = 30"*. so prime labelling isn't that perfect for this kind of tasks? :(

Comment: @MarcAndreson: At $t=30$, the guards change at $A,X,C$, so no staying-guard has line-of-sight to the guard change happening at $B$, putting the paintings near $B$ at risk.